# Meeting accept response stuck in outbox in Mac Outlook 2011

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

Meeting accept response mails are stuck in my outbox and Outlook displays an error message:

> An unknown error has occurred in Outlook.
>
> Mail could not be sent.
>
> Error code -50

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I'm troubleshooting this problem right now for a user. Was sad to see no one has given a response. What I've found so far is that error code -50 is paramErr - Error in user parameter list. And I've found a few solutions but I have yet to test them to see if they work. So attempt at your own risk!

Copied [from online forums](http://www.office.mvps.org/error/number.html):

> - One user found this solution: Run "Remove Office", then run Repair Permissions. Install from your CD and apply all updates. Restart and
>     then run Repair Permissions again.
> - Another cause for this error was found by [name omitted]: I had a semicolon in my outgoing server name.
> - Another user reported this fixed the issue for them: Try creating a new Entourage identity and setting up your email account. When the
>     email address is verified with the new identity and you receive your
>     e-mail, then try switching back to the identity that you had a problem
>     with and check your mail. This solved the problem for me.
> - [Name Omitted], reported this solution: I found old mails in my outbox that were never delivered (for an unknown reason), but
>     everytime I wrote a new mail, Entourage tried to send them again,
>     leading to a -50 error everytime. Deleting these old entries in my
>     outbox resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I seem to have cracked it.
I somehow changed my Date and Time on my local machine and saved it. Issue was that the mail synched during this brief change. I had 20 mails trying to synch mails from my future changed date as I had subsequently changed my local time back to the normal day.
This caused much confusion on the exchange eg: last synched 30 January 2015 and my local time and date is the 20th January. 
I moved all my mails out of my inbox including sent items to an archive and re-synched my mail account. This seems to have fixed the error code 50 on trying to synch my mail.